# Copy image to clipboard with javascript in Chrome only

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, clipboard, copy-paste

Is it possible to have javascript copy an image to a clipboard? I'm looking to replicate the "Copy Image" function that Chrome has when you Right/Control click an image in the browser.

I've seen solutions for text, some Flash based solutions for text as well. But I'm interested in image data only. And only in Chrome. Don't care about IE or FF for this requirement.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy Image to Clipboard from Browser in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321606/copy-image-to-clipboard-from-browser-in-javascript)

Comment: In my case, this is a browser extension, in case that's relevant.

Comment: @noɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Do you want to copy the image data? If so, why? Where do you intend to paste it?

Comment: @GökhanKurt I intend for the end-user to have the image be pasteable into , for example Microsoft Word and Photo editing tools. Simulate the effect of the right click menu.

Comment: Use html2canvas to convert your image to canvas then you can copy. hope that will help you

Answer (score 9):

**Update**: From [Chrome 43](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/04/chrome-43-beta-web-midi-and-upgrading.html), [Firefox 41](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/41), [Opera 29](https://dev.opera.com/blog/opera-29/) and [Safari 10](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html) onwards, any website can do `document.execCommand("copy")` and `document.execCommand("cut")` anytime.

---

**Outdated**:

Just as [Copy Image to Clipboard from Browser in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321606/copy-image-to-clipboard-from-browser-in-javascript) explained, it is a security hole if any website is allowed to take/put data into users' OS just because she navigated to a malicious website.

If you are targeting Chrome only, you have two solutions.

1. Write a Chrome Extension and ask your users to install it.
2. Write a Chrome App and ask your users to install it. Your users need not to be running your Chrome App. Scripts in the domains the installed Chrome App registers will automatically gain this privilege.

Your app/extension has to declare the `clipboardWrite` privilege (see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).

Then you can call `document.execCommand("Copy")` after you have manipulated the `window.selection` to point to the image you want to copy.

Comment: I tried on Chrome 41 on my Chrome App with correct clipboard permission, window.selection follows a document.execCommand("Copy") does not work. and clipboardData.setData(mimeType, blob/or/file) does not work either. it happens only for image, everything else(text, htm, my own data format) seems work fine.

Comment: Can I do this in a firefox extension?

Comment: How do I do this specifically for images?

Answer (score 2):

In 2020, it can be done with the Asynchronous Clipboard API, see here: https://arnellebalane.com/blog/async-clipboard-api/ (includes a demo).

Comment: +1 for the Async Clipboard API. Please see this [article](https://web.dev/async-clipboard/#write()) for a detailed write-up, including current limiations.

Comment: In 2021 this is the way to copy an image to the clipboard. Still not possible in Firefox.