# How can I copy file (.jpg) to clipboard, using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to copy an image file (jpg) to clipboard, using JavaScript, in internet explorer.
I can to copy data using this function:

```
function copyToClipboard(s) {
 clipboardData.setData('my text',s);         
}
```

Can I do something similar, but getting an image file and save it into clipboard?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `clipboardData` is now deprecated. Please check the `ClipboardEvent` API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy Image to Clipboard from Browser in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321606/copy-image-to-clipboard-from-browser-in-javascript)